# Making a list card component more reusable react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a list card component which displays information about phones (name, brand, quantity and if it's available or not). I'm trying to expand this functionality by also using the same component to display information about books (author, name, availability and review score).
The information about phones and books are stored in two different Json files.

**devices.json:**

```
{
  "devices": {
    "deviceList": [
      {
        "name": "iPhone X",
        "deviceType": "Mobile",
        "os": "iOS",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "bookedUntil": [
          {
            "date": "2022-02-13"
          },
        ],
        "quantity": 3,
      },
      {...}
```

**books.json**

```
{
  "books": {
    "bookList": [
      {
        "title": "Clean Code",
        "id": "137420wgf0",
        "author": "Robert Cecil Martin",
        "rating": {
          "score": 4.65,
          "userCount": 17
        },
        "bookedUntil": null,
      },
      {...}
```

My objective is that I could pass either of those Json files to the component and display the cards for books or devices. But the problem I'm facing is that in the component where there is the *name* of the device there should be the *author* of the book. Same for the device *brand* and book *title*.

My lack of knowledge in React is slowing my progress a bit, but I understand that I need to pass down either the book or device object through props to the component. But because of the problem I mentioned before where *name* and *author* are not under the same name I get an error that there's no *bookList.name, bookList.brand* in the Json file, so I'm quite stumped on how to proceed further.

Here's my **listCard component:**

```
const ReservationsListCard = ({

  device: { id, name, author, title, brand, bookedUntil, quantity, image },

  liked = false,
}) => {
 
  return (
    <div className="reservations-list-card">
      <a
        href={"/device/" + id}
        className="reservations-list-card__image-wrapper"
      >
        <img
          className="reservations-list-card__image-wrapper__image"
          alt="device"
          src={image}
        />
      </a>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__brand ">{brand}</div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__icon">
        {liked ? <FilledHeartIcon /> : <OutlineHeartIcon />}
      </div>
      <a
        href={"/device/" + id}
        className="reservations-list-card__name-wrapper"
      >
        <div className="reservations-list-card__name-wrapper__name">
          {name}
        </div>
      </a>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__availability">
        {stateIcon}&nbsp; {stateText}&nbsp;
        {minDate && getParsedDate(minDate)}
      </div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__quantity">
        QUANTITY: {quantity}
      </div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__buttons">
        <Button size="medium" type="text" href={"/device/" + id}>
          View More
        </Button>
        <Button size="medium" to="/device">
          Book
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReservationsListCard.propTypes = {
  device: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  liked: PropTypes.bool,
};

ReservationsListCard.defaultProps = {
  liked: false,
};

export default ReservationsListCard;
```

And this is how I'm passing the **devices.json** file to the component:

```
 <ReservationsListCard key={device.id} liked={false} device={device} />
```

Answer (score 0):

First approche:
generalize the component, rename the props, e.g -> Headline, title1, title2, etc...
Then map your data to this.

(recommended)
Second Approche:
Create a new listCard Component for every type: listCardDevice, listCardBooks, etc.
Imagine adding a property later or you want to display new things (Cars, Music,...). That would be a pain to do :)